# Run a script/application after login but before X in OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, authentication, opensuse, autologin

I have an appliance of OpenSUSE 11.3 and I would like to do this:

Run an autostart script AFTER LOGIN and BEFORE any startX command. 
My SO is configured to autologin some user, so is also configured to get to runlevel 3. If I set to runlevel 5, automatically will run graphical system to make a graphical login, and I don't want it in this way; so that's the reason that I set in runlevel 3.

What files I have to edit/create to make this automated task?

Note: I have no tools to manage this system (if needed), because it's a lite installation, so the only way (I think) is editing the files myself.

Comment: After what login type exactly? To display a graphical login, you have to have an X server already.

Answer (score 1):

I did GPS application (openSuSE 11.1) in 2009 for HP customers of my company and the job was similar to yours.
From my memory:
I opened autostart (Administration) and did a simple, just 3-6 lines of bash script. 
It worked well. You need to search a couple of similar scripts at SuSE web site. I found there a couple of templates.
I hope it would be useful.

Comment: If you know of the location of the scripts, why not provide a link to them instead of telling the user to go search for them?

Answer (score 1):

I just configure the Suse Studio builder to have runlevel at 3, with autologin. I used the .bash_profile file located in the /home/someuser directory, this file is an script which runs when the user log in (but no when a user opens a terminal or shell). So I was able to run my script and after that "startx" command.

Also, I had to change something (I don't remember what)to make the LXDE Desktop start with startx command, but that was optional because I could use the default lxde startup command.